# How to get an empty macro to expand in Cython

Tags: cython

I have a C header with many empty macros. Like `#define LA_CC` without value. How to define this in Cython? I cannot find any documents to explain this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You only have to define the parts of the C interface you actually want to use in Cython. This kind of macro is usually used to hide implementation details, so you would just ignore it in Cython